# Javascript RegExp Replace to get times

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to solve a RegExp problem. I found 80% of the pattern. If someone help me with the remaining 20% would help a lot.

Eg String:

```
var str = "Digital Presentation;Stadium Seating (11:05 AM), (1:40), 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM";
```

My Pattern so far:

```
var patt = /[^0-9|:|,|\b\sAM\b|\b\sPM\b]/g;
```

For:

```
var result = str.replace(patt, '');
```

What I get is:

```
P 11:05 AM, 1:40, 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM
```

My Desired result is:

```
11:05 AM, 1:40, 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzYwu/1/

All I need is to match spaceAM and spacePM, Instead for my pattern it matches all occurrence of P, A, M and space.

Another string example is:

```
Digital Presentation;Movies and Mimosas (11:00 AM)
```

What I get for my pattern is:

```
PM  M 11:00 AM
```

What I like to get is:

```
11:00 AM
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one: ```[0-9]{1, 2}:[0-9]{1,2}( [AP]M)?```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is the problem:

```
var patt = /[^0-9|:|,|\b\sAM\b|\b\sPM\b]/g;
```

Its not doing what you think it is doing.

Inside character class it will remove everything but digit, colon, pipe, comma, literal \b, A, M and P

Correct regex based code is:

```
str = "Digital Presentation;Stadium Seating (11:05 AM), (1:40), 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM"
str.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}( +[AP]M)?/g).join(', ');
//=> 11:05 AM, 1:40, 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for the answer. But I dont want to match all A,M and P. All I want is AM and PM.

Comment: see updated code. I understand you don't want pipe but you CANNOT give group strings like `\bAM\b` inside character class. character class will treat each as individual character thus making it `(\\b|A|M)`

Comment: Awesome Anubhava. Thank you so much. It did work. I am not that good with RegEx Patterns. :)

Comment: \s instead of the space before AM/PM please :)

Comment: You're welcome. Read more about regex: http://regular-expressions.info and don't forget to mark the answer accepted.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: `\s` will match new lines also and I guess that's not needed by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Danstahr's regex to work

```
var timereg = /[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}( \b(AM|PM))?/g

"Digital Presentation;Stadium Seating (11:05 AM), (1:40), 4:30, 7:30, 10:50 PM".match(/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}( \b(AM|PM))?/g)
//=> ["11:05 AM", "1:40", "4:30", "7:30", "10:50 PM"]
```